# Difference between an adjective clause and a noun clause in apposition to a noun or a pronoun?

Tags: differences, clauses, subordinate-clauses

What is the difference between an adjective clause and a noun clause in apposition to a noun or a pronoun?
I am confused because the examples I found are quite similar.

Noun clause in apposition to a noun or pronoun:

> Your statement that you didn't take the money can’t be believed.

Adjective clause:

> Fruit that is grown organically is expensive.

I would also appreciate it if you could provide more examples of these clauses with their main clause and subordinate clause marked (main clause in bold please).

How can I differentiate between and identify them?

Comment: When a noun takes a clause as complement, that complement is not in apposition to the noun. And the content clause “that you didn’t take the money” is undoubtedly a complement of “statement”, so it can’t be an appositive modifier (note that appositives are modifiers not complements). Also, to qualify as an appositive, the clause must not only be an entailment of the whole NP, but it must also be grammatical, and I’d say that "That you didn't take the money can't be believed" is ungrammatical.  In your 2nd example, the _that_- clause is clearly a relative one, so it cannot be appositive.

Comment: @BillJ: I agree, especially about the word *appositive*. The only thing is that I do think *that you didn't take the money can't be believed* is OK, though probably inferior to *the statement that...*

Comment: @Cerberus A useful test is to replace "that" with "the fact that", which here would yield "The fact that you didn't take the money can't be believed", which seems contradictory to me.

Comment: @BillJ: I kind of see where you're coming from, but why is that a good test? And how about *that he didn't take the money has been proven*? It fails the test, but would you consider it grammatical? Again, I agree that adding *it* or *the statement/assertion/etc.* is better than ∅.

Comment: @Cerberus No, it would pass the test and prove that your example ("the fact that he didn't take the money ...") was grammatical, and it showed that the OP's was not. But most importantly, I see the OP's _that_- clause as a complement, not a modifier and thus not an appositive.

Comment: @Cerberus If you want an example of a content clause that is an appositive, you need to find a noun that doesn't take content clause complements!

Comment: @BillJ: But...I don't think you can prove a fact? It's not a fact until after you have proven it? At any rate, I think that test has an important semantic element, but you want a test that is only syntactic. So what is the exact difference between a complement and a modifier? A modifier is never essential (while a complement obviously is)?

Comment: @BillJ To your second comment: how would you define apposition? *She objected to his first statement, that all Egyptians were frivolous.* Would you call this appositive?

Comment: @Cerberus "She objected (to his) that all Egyptians were frivolous" ???? The content clause looks like a complement of "statement" to me.

Comment: @BillJ: Sorry, I had Cleopatra in mind: she is objecting to Marc Anthony's stating that all Egyptians were frivolous. I suppose that was ambiguous. Wouldn't you call that an appositive? The *that* clause looks to be in apposition to *his first statement* to me.

Answer (score 3):

1 Relative clause (adjective clause): Fruit that is grown organically is expensive.

2 That-clause (noun-clause) as attribute of a noun: Your statement that you didn't take the money can't be believed.

The structure of the that-clause in 1 and 2 is different. In 1 "that" has subject character; you could replace "that" by "it".

In 2 you have a subject (you) after "that".

You can add a relative clause to any noun. But that-clauses of type 2 are only possible after special nouns such as the fact, the idea, the statement, the suggestion and similar nouns. These nouns just give an information about the nature of the that-clause. What is said in the that-clause is a fact or a statement, a suggestion, an idea or something similar.

In 2 you can drop "the statement" and say "That you didn't take the money can't be believed". You can use "statement" after the that-clause: That you didn't take the money (your statement) can't be believed.

Comment: This answer is good, except one thing; *In 1 "that" has subject character; you could replace "that" by "it"*: this (wrongly) suggests to me that the *that* in an adjectival/relative clause has to be the subject. But *the fruit that they gave me is expensive* has the same construction even though *that* is the object of *gave* in the relative clause.

Comment: @Cerberus  Right you are. I wanted to add that the relative pronoun can be subject or object - but, to be honest, I didn't want to go into details about relative clauses, the post is long enough as it is. And I think the problem aren't relative clauses, they are relatively easy. At least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

In sentence 1: fruit that is grown organicall is expensive.....this is no doubt a adjective clause.....the clause “that is grown organically” does not mean what is fruit....rather it means about fruit....so it is adj CLS

```
         But
```

In second sentence ...“that u did not take the money”and  “statement”..is the same thing....so it is noun in apposition and noun clause....